# How to run synchronous code after redux saga channel closes

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I am trying to execute a code after the saga is cancelled/closed, or after the channel is closed.

This is a simple example:

1. Create a channel that holds some random numbers
2. Create some forks to do some expensive calculation on each number.
3. Add some random numbers to the channel
4. After the channel is closed, i want to execute some code.

**But what im missing is how to execute code after all of this is finished.** (in this example, a simple `console.log`)

Code is here:

```
const {
    take, fork, put, call, delay, all, join,
} = require('redux-saga/effects');
const { channel, runSaga } = require('redux-saga');

function* doSomeExpensiveThing(citiesChannel) {
    while (true) {
        const payload = yield take(citiesChannel);

        // do some expensive operation with each number
        // simulated here with a random 0-1000ms delay
        yield delay(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10)) * 100);
        console.log('Finished number: ', payload);
    }
}

function* bootstrapSaga(numberOfWorkers) {
    console.log('Bootrstrapping saga.');

    // create a channel to queue all incoming numbers
    const numbersQueue = yield call(channel);
    const workers = [];

    // create N worker 'threads' to receive items put into the queue
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i += 1) {
        workers.push(yield fork(doSomeExpensiveThing, numbersQueue));
    }

    const allNumbers = Array.from(Array(10).keys());

    // add all numbers to the queue
    while (allNumbers.length > 0) {
        yield put(numbersQueue, allNumbers.pop());
    }

    // yield join(workers);
    // yield all(workers.map(w => w.toPromise()));
    // console.log('NEVER HAPPENS');
}

function* mainSaga(numberOfWorkers = 3) {
    console.log('Starting...');

    yield call(bootstrapSaga, numberOfWorkers);
    console.log('ALL DONE.'); // Y U NO WORK?? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 
}

runSaga({}, mainSaga, 5);
```

If it makes it easier, there is a runnable version here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/o40kl
Be sure to open the console on codesandbox

For this example, i tried a few things, like using `yield all(workers)` or `yield join(workers)`. These were just attempts to make the `console.log('ALL DONE')` work.

**Question: What do I have to modify on my script in order for it to do so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: In order to have this to work, we will need to close the channel after `put`ing the work to be done by the workers:

```
numbersQueue.close();
```

Then we can use `all` effect to wait for all the tasks to resolve:

```
yield all(workers.map(w => w.toPromise()));
```

> Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to
>   run multiple Effects in parallel and wait for all of them to complete.
>   It's quite the corresponding API to standard Promise#all.

**Update**: I have updated this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-issue-template-zpcqc) and added the necessary modifications so you can see it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! Not sure what is happening here though, it seems half the numbers are being skipped, as in the console log there are only 5 "numbers"  entries. I guess if we do `return`  inside the `while (true)`, then the loop is only ever executed once.

Comment: @VitorM - You are right! it because I returned `Promise.resolve()` which ends each worker after taking care of a single task (number). It seems that the channel should be closed after the work have been passed to be handled by the workers. Thank you for your attention, I have updated my answer and the codesandbox as well.